# Converting to First order logic

Tags: logic

I had convert a small paragraph into First order logic. Could some one check whether it is correct or not. Information as follows.

```
"Anyone who has catarrh will sneeze. if anyone allergic to animal danger 
or dust mite then they will have catarrh. Maya is  allergic to animal danger."
```

This is I did.

```
1. ∃x p(x) ∧ c(x) ∧ s(x).
2. ∃x p(x) ∧ a(x) V d(x) --> c(x)
3. a(maya).
```

Please help me to solve  this.

Comment: How came forall for beginning. Because Anyone indicates a single person.

Answer (score 1):

Your answers for 1 and 2 do not look right. Your answer for number 3 looks reasonable.

The first two statements in English do not require that any such person exist; and they aren't saying that just one such person exists. You should translate to something more like:

```
1. forall x . p(x) and c(x) implies s(x)
2. forall x . p(x) and (a(x) or d(x)) implies c(x)
3. a(maya)
```